# can't access viarible in the target php files

Tags: php, html

At first I write a simple hotel.php

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">

        <?php
        $info = $_GET['type'];//works well $info get num= 1;
        ?>

        <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">order</h3>
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
            <form action="sendmail.php" method="get">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="name">name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" vlaue="" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="phone">phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="name2" vlaue="" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <input class="invisible" type="text" name="room_info" value="<?php $_GET['type'];?>">
                        <label for="slider-2">num</label>
                        <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" data-mini="true" data-highlight="true" min="1" max="6" value="4" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="arrive-time">a_time</label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="arrive-time" id="arrive-time" value="" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="leave-time">b_time</label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="leave-time" id="arrive-time" value="" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="reset" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">reset</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a" data-ajax="false">sbumit</div>
                        <fieldset>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </form><!--end form-->
        </div>

    </div>
```

It's strange that $info = $_GET['type']; works well and the $info get the value correctly.
but when I click the submit button.

in target webpage sendmail.php

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
$phone=$_GET['phone'];
$roominfo=$_GET['room_info'];
$num=$_GET['slider-2'];
$a_time=$_GET['arrive-time'];
$b_time=$_GET['leave-time'];
```

all get the right information except the roominfo is null.
what's the problem with this">I try this">but steel not work

Comment: I'm assuming the class=invisible hides the input field? Why not just use a hidden field? Also what is $_GET['type']?

Comment: Is it just me, or are you not even creating an input for `room_info`?

Comment: @user2071225 user don't need to see the info .$_GET['type'] get a number ,for example like 1. the first works well.but when it comes to <input class="invisible" type="text" name="room_info" value="<?php $_GET['type'];?>"> seems not work..

Comment: The value needs to be echoed or it won't display in the the input. See answers below: `value="<?php echo $_GET['type'];?>"`

Comment: To make it invisible, use `hidden` : `<input type="hidden" name="room_info" value="<?php echo $_GET['type']; ?>">`

Comment: @djidi  I try your solution,but it does not work.the sendmail.php can't get the info throught

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo:

```
<input class="invisible" type="text" name="room_info" value="<?php $_GET['type'];?>">
```

to

```
<input class="invisible" type="text" name="room_info" value="<?php echo $_GET['type'];?>">
```

**EDIT**
     OP seems to want this element hidden so that's why there is **invisible** class. Well, you don't need to create a class for this case. You can use [hidden](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php).

```
<input type="hidden" name="room_info" value="<?php echo $_GET['type'];?>">
```

Comment: Same time same answer.. :-)

Comment: Yeah! :) OP just forgot a simple echo. We thought of the same possible answer.

Comment: i try echo .but it appear on the webpage.and I want to put it into an hidden area.so the user will not see.that why I use invisible

Comment: Alright, well see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use  echo

```
 <input class="invisible" type="text" name="room_info" value="<?php echo $_GET['type'];?>">
```